# When to use a constructor and when to use OnInit

Tags: javascript, angular

So i have been reading in angular 2 that there are two ways to do the same thing but i do not know its fundamental difference if there is any.

Consider the following

**Constructor**

```
export class MyComponent {
  myAge: number;

  constructor(){
   this.myAge = 24;
  }
}
```

**OnInit**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
  myAge: number;

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.myAge = 24;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is related to the class instantiation and has nothing to do with Angular2. I mean a constructor can be used on any class. You can put in it some initialization processing for the newly created instance.

The second one corresponds to a lifecycle hook of Angular2 components:

- `ngOnChanges` is called when an input or output binding value changes
- `ngOnInit` is called after the first `ngOnChanges`

So I would use `ngOnInit` if initialization processing relies on bindings of the component (for example component parameters defined with `@Input`), otherwise the constructor would be enough...

In your case using the constructor is enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! One question, ngOnInit does seem like an angular 2 constructor, is it bad to use that all the time? is there any performance problem??

Comment: You're welcome! No it's not bad... It's just called later than the constructor in the component lifecycle.

Comment: when an output binding value changes, ngOnChanges is not called. It's called only when an input binding value changes.